# Toggle div based on id

Tags: javascript

Drawing a silly blank on this, but I need to be able to toggle a div based on the id that's clicked (so the english should only show english and french should only show french). So the english div should show at start, and when you click on french link, the english hides and show the french div. Both links currently toggle both divs when clicking.

```js
function langToggle(id) {
   var english = document.getElementById("english"); 
   var frech = document.getElementById("french");

   english.style.display = (
       english.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none"); 
   french.style.display = (
       french.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none"); 
}
```

```css
a {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="langToggle(english)">English</a>
<a onclick="langToggle(french)">French</a>
<div id="english">
    <p>English</p>
</div>
<div id="french" style="display:none;">
    <p>French</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You arent using the parameter passed into your `langToggle()` function, and you also aren't making the divs visible anywhere in the function.

Comment: Typo here too: `frech`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did was a toggle function. But what you need is just to clear all the elements, and set only the one you need.

See the modified Javascript.

```js
function langToggle(id) {
   english.style.display = "none";
   french.style.display = "none";
   id.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
a {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="langToggle(english)">English</a>
<a onclick="langToggle(french)">French</a>
<div id="english">
    <p>English</p>
</div>
<div id="french" style="display:none;">
    <p>French</p>
</div>
```